# Gorilla websocket how to unmarshal binary data into JSON?

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm following the [chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat) provided by gorilla.

I still can get to unmarshal the json data sent. Should I do this in the `readPump()`:

```
func (c *ChatClient) readPump() {
    defer func() {
        c.hub.unregisterChan <- c
        c.conn.Close()
    }()
    c.conn.SetReadLimit(maxMessageSize)
    c.conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pongWait))
    c.conn.SetPongHandler(func(string) error { c.conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pongWait)); return nil })
    for {
        _, message, err := c.conn.ReadMessage()
        // =================MY CODE START=============
        var comment Comment
        err = c.conn.ReadJSON(comment)
        if err != nil {
            LogErr("readjson()", err)
            break
        }
        err = json.Unmarshal(message, comment)
        if err != nil {
            LogErr("readjson()", err)
            break
        }
        // =================MY CODE END=============

        if err != nil {
            if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure) {
                LogErr("IsUnexpectedCloseError()", err)
            }
            break
        }
        message = bytes.TrimSpace(bytes.Replace(message, newline, space, -1))
        c.hub.broadcastChan <- message
    }
}
```

or in the `writePump()`

```
func (c *ChatClient) writePump() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(pingPeriod)
    defer func() {
        ticker.Stop()
        c.conn.Close()
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case message, ok := <-c.send:
            c.conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(writeWait))

            // CLOSE
            if !ok {
                c.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, []byte{})
                return
            }

            w, err := c.conn.NextWriter(websocket.BinaryMessage)
            if err != nil {
                LogErr("c.conn.NextWriter", err)
                return
            }
            w.Write(message)

            // Add queued chat messages to the current websocket message.
            n := len(c.send)
            for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                w.Write(newline)
                w.Write(<-c.send)
            }

            if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
                LogErr("w.Close()", err)
                return
            }
        case <-ticker.C:
            c.conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(writeWait))
            if err := c.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.PingMessage, nil); err != nil {
                LogErr("c.conn.WriteMessage()", err)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The LogErr() methods don't print any message. Totally lost here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application reads two messages on each iteration through the loop and attempts to unmarshal both to `comment`.  Read one message only.

The application calls `ReadJSON` and `Unmarshal` incorrectly and the error returned from these functions explains why: the application is attempting to unmarshal to a non-pointer.

The application also sends the raw bytes of the message to a channel. That looks like it might be a leftover from whatever you are copying, so I'll ignore that in the remainder of the answer.

Here's the fixed loop:

```
for {
    var comment Comment
    err = c.conn.ReadJSON(&comment)
    if err != nil {
        if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure) {
            LogErr("IsUnexpectedCloseError()", err)
        }
        break
    }
    // Do something with comment
}
```

Comment: thanks @ThunderCat when I put that code in the for now connection just triggers `webSocket.onclose()` on the client side without throwing any errors on backend. I put debugger and doesn't seem to enter that portion of code. The event onClose returned in JS looks   {code: 1006, composed: false, currentTarget: WebSocket `{url: "ws://localhost:3001/chat", readyState: 3, eventPhase: 2, isTrusted: true, 
srcElement: WebSocket {url: "ws://localhost:3001/chat", readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, target: WebSocket {url: "ws://localhost:3001/chat", readyState: 3,...}`

Comment: The calls to c.conn.ReadJSON and json.Unmarshal in the original code return errors, but you didn't see any errors logged.  You should confirm that LogErr actually works as expected. You also note that the program does not seem to enter the code on the server.  Perhaps the client is connecting to a different endpoint or a different server entirely.

Comment: why does this only work when I send JSON as a string like this:                 `webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(comment))` if I try `webSocket.send(comment)` it doesn't work

Comment: `webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(comment))` encodes the comment in the format expected by the server.  `webSocket.send(comment)` fails because the argument is not [one of the allowed types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send#Parameters).